# RoutingMissingException while indexing with NEST library

Tags: search-engine, elasticsearch, nest

I have specified document mapping in my code using TypeMapping, while indexing I started seeing the following exception

{"error":"RoutingMissingException[routing is required for [search2]/[ImageDocument]/[2039810546]]","status":500}

And I didn't find any way to specify routing using NEST while specifying the typemappings!
Any clue where do we specify the routing parameter while indexing or at the time mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use IndexParameters argument while indexing and specify the routing

```
        IndexParameters indexParams = new IndexParameters() { Routing = "id" };
        var resp = ConnectedClient.Index(doc, "IndexName", "typeName", id, indexParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

In NEST v2.4, you can use the selector parameter to specify the routing.

```
public IIndexResponse Index<T>(T @object, Func<IndexDescriptor<T>, IIndexRequest> selector = null) where T : class;
```

And use it like this:

```
var routingId = 1;
var resp = client.Index(doc, r => r.Routing(routingId));
```